# Where to find the headers of its deployed heroku application?

Tags: django, heroku

This is a pretty short question. I deployed a Django [app](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com) to heroku and would like to have access to the contents of that app's security headers. The subject is not well documented on the Internet. I don't know the procedure to access it. Thanks!

Comment: `request.META`?

Comment: I don't know what it is, about request mode, I haven't set any mode except that my application contains a form that sends data via POST method. If heroku has another mode, it must be the default one because I didn't define any mode during deployment. I'm very bad at heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see your apps security headers, you can do that in any browser in the browser dev tools (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I usually, or just hunt through menus for tools). Go to the network tab, reload and click on the row with the page title (eg '/' for the homepage of the URL you provide).  The request headers for that page should appear in their own section of the tools.

If you want to edit your headers, have a look at the docs for [security middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) for some elements you can include in your settings.py file.

For recommendations on what settings should be set to you can get an analysis at at securityheaders.com or observatory.mozilla.org

There are addtional django modules for helping with any additional headers like a Content Security Policy. I use Django-CSP for that one.